# How to put back the WAMP server Offline? Where is the option?

Tags: php, apache, web, wamp

**I installed Wamp 3.1.3 64 bit.**
There are 3 icon colour basically in WAMP **red,orange & green**
These functionality is also known to me,so not describing.
 But there is also another icon a ***green back with red dot and yellow lines***. By google-ing I came to know that for *Indicating The Server is Online*. So Every thing is ok till now. *I put my server Online*.
But the problem is now how can i put the server back to offline? I can't find any **PUT OFFLINE** option. I tried with editting the

> httpd.conf

&

> vhost-htttpd.conf

files by setting everything-

```
Require Local
```

But Nothing changes . I also restarted the whole system. The Icon is same.
**So how can i Put this back offline?**
Edit:
I want to make it back local only ie the color of icon back to **green only** and  *services should run and server works locally*.

Comment: hey someone in the world !!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and fixed it following the french forum post linked by Roshana. By the way, the Online/Offline feature no longer works even after the fix. You have to use virtual hosts to put your local site "online".

Open C:/wamp64/scripts/refresh.php in a text editor and replace the following :

```
// management of online / offline mode
$c_OnOffLine = 'off';
if ($wampConf['status'] == 'online')
{
    $tpl = str_replace('images_off.bmp', 'images_on.bmp',$tpl);
  $tpl = str_replace($w_serverOffline, $w_serverOnline,$tpl);
  $tpl = str_replace('onlineOffline.php on', 'onlineOffline.php off', $tpl);
  $tpl = str_replace($w_putOnline,$w_putOffline,$tpl);
  $c_OnOffLine = 'on';
}
// management of item put online
if($wampConf['MenuItemOnline'] == 'on') {
    $changeServMenu = ';WAMPPUTONLINE
';
    $changeServMenu .= <<< EOF
Type: item; Caption: "${w_putOnline}"; Action: multi; Actions: onlineoffline
EOF;
    $tpl = str_replace(';WAMPPUTONLINE',$changeServMenu,$tpl);

    $changeServMenu = ';WAMPONLINEOFFLINESTART
';
    $changeServMenu .= <<< EOF
[onlineoffline]
Action: run; FileName: "${c_phpExe}"; Parameters: "onlineOffline.php on";WorkingDir: "${c_installDir}/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: run; FileName: "${c_phpCli}"; Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "${c_installDir}/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: ${c_apacheService}; ServiceAction: restart;
Action: resetservices;
Action: readconfig;
EOF;
    $tpl = str_replace(';WAMPONLINEOFFLINESTART',$changeServMenu,$tpl);
}
```

By:

```
// management of item put online
if($wampConf['MenuItemOnline'] == 'on') {
    $changeServMenu = ';WAMPPUTONLINE
';
    $changeServMenu .= <<< EOF
Type: item; Caption: "${w_putOnline}"; Action: multi; Actions: onlineoffline
EOF;
    $tpl = str_replace(';WAMPPUTONLINE',$changeServMenu,$tpl);

    $changeServMenu = ';WAMPONLINEOFFLINESTART
';
    $changeServMenu .= <<< EOF
[onlineoffline]
Action: run; FileName: "${c_phpExe}"; Parameters: "onlineOffline.php on";WorkingDir: "${c_installDir}/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: run; FileName: "${c_phpCli}"; Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "${c_installDir}/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: ${c_apacheService}; ServiceAction: restart;
Action: resetservices;
Action: readconfig;
EOF;
    $tpl = str_replace(';WAMPONLINEOFFLINESTART',$changeServMenu,$tpl);

    // management of online / offline mode
    $c_OnOffLine = 'off';
    if ($wampConf['status'] == 'online')
    {
        $tpl = str_replace('images_off.bmp', 'images_on.bmp',$tpl);
        $tpl = str_replace($w_serverOffline, $w_serverOnline,$tpl);
        $tpl = str_replace('onlineOffline.php on', 'onlineOffline.php off', $tpl);
        $tpl = str_replace($w_putOnline,$w_putOffline,$tpl);
        $c_OnOffLine = 'on';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, this is how I fixed it in 3 steps:

1. First, I simply made a copy of the two following folders (located in the wamp64 folder):

   ```
   \bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\**data** 
   \**www**
   ```
2. After, I uninstalled and reinstalled WampServer.
3. Finally copy-paste the previously 2 folders, adding their content to the fresh installed new folders and that's all!

You also might be interested by this link (in french):
[WampServer 3 Online / Offline](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?1,150968,150968)

I hope it helps you.